# Can't open google-chrome stable newest

Tags: google-chrome

```
mr2uang@mr2uang-MS-7798:~$ google-chrome Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[7832:7832:1025/191444:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[7832:7832:1025/191444:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK themeerror: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[7832:7832:1025/191444:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK themeerror: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[7832:7832:1025/191444:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK themeerror: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[7832:7832:1025/191444:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can i fix them?

After execting the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
```

---

```
mr2uang@mr2uang-MS-7798:~$ google-chrome 
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 492:elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion((reloc->r_info) & 0xffffffff) == 8' failed!`
```

Comment: are you using 32-bit version of chrome?

Comment: what is output of `sudo apt-get check`

Comment: all done. after reinstalled my google-chrome working fine. i hope my next restart google-chrome still working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question the main error message (but very minor,nothing to do with opening chrome) is

> Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

If still getting error

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

I too get the rest of the messages in terminal:

Example:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ google-chrome
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[2889:2889:1025/192524:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2889:2889:1025/192524:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2889:2889:1025/192524:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2889:2889:1025/192524:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2889:2889:1025/192524:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(223)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

If still not working try to reinstall google-chrome-stable

```
 sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
 rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf
```

(The first command removes the package and second command removes custom settings )

The new error

> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:492:elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion((reloc->r_info) & 0xffffffff) == 8' failed!

It is just a disk or memory corruption issue.If it is *memory* ,  **reboot** should clear.If it is disk, then **reinstalling** the affected package should fix it.

You can install chrome-stable from [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)

Comment: please accept my edit at your question and add "what ever error message you want to add" to __question__ please

Comment: I'm using Chrome 64 bit. and updated my question.

Comment: please read your self your question, first you mentioned chrome-stable ,now chromium . What are you using ?

Comment: This happen after i installed ibus

Comment: how to reinstall the affected package?

Comment: in this  case "chrome-stable" so remove (use the commands in answer) and install from link at bottom